# Passing variables through a JavaScript modified form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a search page which displays a table of results. I want to add some functionality with Javascript. The entire table is encapsulated within a form, and each item on the table has several actions you can perform; One example is `Add comment`.

I am able to pass all the other form variables correctly as they are static. The issue I am having is being able to pass the `ID` to the action since it changes for each row of the result. Here is what I have so far (shortened)

Action header:

```
public ActionResult Create( ........., Int ID);
```

View:

```
...

@foreach( var item in Model )
{
    ...
    @Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Create", "Comment", new { ID = Model.ID }, new { onclick = "CommentSubmit(@Model.ID)" })
}
```

Javascript:

```
function CommentSubmit(id) {

            //What do?
    $("#DynForm").attr("action", "/Comment/Create");
    $("#DynForm").submit();
};
```

How can I just Javascript/jQuery to pass in the `ID` in addition to my other form variables?

Kind of a side question, but do I need stop the original anchor from executing (since my javascript is submitting the form)? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create or update an hidden input before submitting your form with the id

```
function CommentSubmit(id) {
    if($("#DynForm #id").length > 0)
        $("#DynForm #id").val(id);
    else
        $("#DynForm").append("<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value='"+id+"' />");

    $("#DynForm").attr("action", "/Comment/Create");
    $("#DynForm").submit();
};
```

Comment: Wow, so it's that easy... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could do this

```
<input type="hidden" name="myID" />


function CommentSubmit(id) {

    $("#myID").val(id);        
    $("#DynForm").attr("action", "/Comment/Create");
    $("#DynForm").submit();
};
```

then in controller just add myID as a parameter

```
Public ActionResult Action(string myID , .... ){

}
```

or , you could just do this

```
 function CommentSubmit(id) {
        //What do?
$("#DynForm").attr("action", "/Comment/Create/" + id);
$("#DynForm").submit();
```

};

the default routing in Asp.Net will use the third part of url as parameter "id"

ex.    {controller}/{action}/{id}